# How to boot Linux on MacBook Pro 2016

Tags: linux, macos, boot, macbook-pro

I have been trying to boot Kali Linux on my MacBook Pro and it doesn't work. I only have USB-C ports on this computer so I purchased a USB-C to USB 3.0 adapter. Could this be causing the problem? I have tried the bootable USB on my 2009 MacBook Pro and it works flawlessly. I try to boot by turning off my computer and then holding option when it turns on. I have also tried to hold down 'C' while booting with no success. All I can see is my Windows partition I have made and my macOS partition. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious, did you buy an Apple adapter or a third party adapter? I've booted a 2016 touch bar MacBook Pro to macOS from a USB 3.0 flash drive via an Apple USB C to USB adapter (well, actually it was one of Apple's A/V multiport adapters that also has a USB type-A port). So I know that much works.

Comment: By the way, if your goal is to specifically boot Kali Linux from the USB flash drive, you might want to edit your question to specify that; otherwise people might give you answers involving installing Kali on a partition of the internal SSD.

Comment: This is the current state of Linux on the MacBook Pro 2016: https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux . Sorry :/

Answer (score -1):

See this [link](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7), its a gist on the current update (updated 1 hr ago)

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer, do not include just a link